# NW.js Spotlight Integration in OSX

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, spotlight

I want to develop an application, that can be used within the spotlight search.

The user should be able to search for specific "methods" (I don't know how to call it) of the app and the app should then run this method.

Is there a way to integrate the non-document-based Spotlight Indexing in a node-webkit Application?

Comment: Just looking at the docs, it looks like you'll have to create a custom file type (and set your application as the default handler of it), provide metadata about the file, and provide a spotlight importer. There doesn't appear to be a non-document based solution... even most built-in apps use a document model (see System>Library>Preferences Panes)

Comment: @TennysonH I just found [this Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SpotlightCoreData/Articles/recordLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008065-CH101-SW2) and thought i could use this :S